# when an old .xsp page is requested the log is filled up with error messages

Tags: xpages

UPDATE 16Nov:  The problem is where users are accessing invalid urls to xpages that don't exist.  How can I catch these as normal 404's before they go in as full stacktrace dump in the error log?  i.e. catch them before they go to the XSPLoader

eg
13/11/15 11:24: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page /blog2.xsp because the class xsp.Blog2 could not be found. Please check your spelling.
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:174)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:499)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class xsp.Blog2 in NSF
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:469)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:672)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:186)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:169)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsp.Blog2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:442)
    ... 30 more

Is there a way to stop these?
Seems to be a class not found problem.
It is almost a server log attack.

Answer (score 0):

Every XPage and Custom Control is compiled down to be a Java class, so if an XPage or Custom Control has been removed then it also removes the Java class with the same name.

In my tests, this throws a 404 error, so something is wrong with your application. I can't reproduce that error message, I either get the 404 error or a cached version of the custom control. I would suggest using Project > Clean to completely recompile the project.

Comment: To add to what Paul said, sometimes you have to go as far as removing the icon, shutting down Notes and Designer. Restarting adding icon back, and cleaning.

Comment: I'd recommend ensuring the latest Domino Designer version for better stability. In Xsp Properties you can set an application to compile against an earlier release of Domino, so there's no chance of using functionality added in a later release.